# How to break free from a while True network loop?

Tags: micropython

I have a simple webserver program which is inside a `while True:` loop. The program starts with:

```
  conn, addr = s.accept()
  print('Got a connection from %s' % str(addr))
  request = conn.recv(1024)
  request = str(request)
  print('Content = %s' % request)
```

... and ends with:

```
  response = web_page()
  conn.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n')
  conn.send('Content-Type: text/html\n')
  conn.send('Connection: close\n\n')
  conn.sendall(response)
  conn.close()
```

I would like to add an alarm function to the program, which means checking for time and comparing it with a saved alarm time every second/minute. However, the code being set up the way it is, the loop "loops" only if the user presses something on the web server website. How can I both make sure the user gets connected and disconnected properly and also check for time every second?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Don't forget to make the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

edit: just seen this is tagged python as well as micropython - this answer is for micropython...

You could use machine.Timer. Use it to create a periodic interrupt with a callback function that does the time check. Start it before the main loop, `t = Timer(0); t.init(mode=Timer.PERIODIC, period=<n>, callback=<callback>)`, both will run "in parallel". More info here
https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.Timer.html

Another approach would be to use uasyncio for the whole process, run an asynchronous webserver (built in to uasyncio) and have the time check as an asynchronous coroutine. Create the server and dump the contents of your 'while' loop into a callback function (gets called on every request so no need for the loop). The timer period may be a little out when the server is busy but there's the advantage of being able to run other coroutines 'in parallel' with these.

```
    import uasyncio as asyncio
        
    my_ip = 192.168.0.0
    port = 5000
    n_s = 1
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        
    def web_page():
        return 'the_web_page.html'

    async def time_check():
        # do the time check etc here
        await asyncio.sleep(n_s)

    async def handle_client(reader, writer):
        request = (await reader.read(1024)).decode('utf8')
        print(request)
        await writer.awrite(
            b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n')
        with open(web_page(), 'rb') as response:
            while True:
                buf = response.read(1024)
                if len(buf):
                    await writer.awrite(buf)
                if len(buf) < 1024:
                    break
        await writer.aclose()
        return True

    loop.create_task(asyncio.start_server(handle_client, my_ip, port))
    loop.create_task(time_check())
    print('Time check and async webserver created, listening on {}:{}'.format(my_ip, port))

    loop.run_forever()
```